# How to test the cpu variant in Gnu asssembler

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, gnu-assembler

I would like to implement some assembly code differently depending on the cpu variant I am assembling for.
I am currently compiling for ARM, and the cpu variant is passed through the "-mcpu" option of GCC. My question is on how to test the variant when in assembly code?

I know how to declare the variant using the .cpu directive (eg. .cpu cortex-m3), but I would like to use different instructions depending on the target core. I think I can do .ifeq , but I was unable to see what to put in the condition field. Does anyone know about this?

Comment: It might be easiest to define a macro on the command line too and make sure you use preprocessed asm files (`.S`).

Comment: I throught about this, but it would mean express the same information under 2 different ways (the -mcpu, and a -D thing). It is source of potential mistakes and headaches, and I would prefer not to do this.
And also, it appears to be possible for some architectures (the CRIS architecture), with weird tests like :
.if ..asm.arch.cris.v32
code for CRIS v32

Comment: You could macro it in your build scripts like `-DARMCPU=$cpu -mcpu=$cpu`, which would slightly clutter them by forcing you to set `cpu=cortex-m3` or whatever separately from the command.

Comment: the unified syntax was a complete fail imo.  two possible paths. the original thumb instructions are compatible across all cores cortex and full size from armv4t to armv7-a,r,m so you could restrict the common code to that instruction set.  the other alternative is the equivalent of ifdefs of some sort be it as mentioned above macros that are brought in in a build type way conditionally or within a body of code, if cortex-m0 then else if armv7-a then, else.  Of expanding on macros, you could simply have a separate file per core and solve this in the build system as you link multiple binaries

Comment: I do not see what is really a fail in this unified syntax. It is much clearer to me than it was with armv4, mixing arm/thumb with the bx each time was a real mess. Indeed I try to have some assembly routines running on Cortex-M0+ (cross compatible with everything from arm-v6m), and optimized versions for armv7-m.

Comment: None of this can work, simply because the gnu assembler is very poor in options. It seems can only include a file containing my definitions. As an example, the option "-D" is described as "This option has no effect whatsoever, but it is accepted to make it more likely that scripts written for other assemblers also work with as.". :(